# Filter a row by column types in a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Right now I have a generic notification function that is triggered after create on a couple of tables in my database (there's a node process on the other end listening for notifications). Here's what my update trigger looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_create() RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify('update_watchers',
    json_build_object(
      'eventType', 'new',
      'type', TG_TABLE_NAME,
      'payload', row_to_json(NEW)
    )::text
  );
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

The problem is, if NEW is too big, this will overflow the limit of 8000 bytes in a couple of limited corner cases (I rarely have a new item in the table that is that big). In the notify_update function, I just report on which columns have changed by listing the column names. That would work here, but what I would *rather* do is only have row_to_json pull out entries from NEW that are of type integer.

That is because sometimes what I'm notifying is "hey there's a new entry in an entity table". The new entry could be from a couple of different tables (documents, profiles, etc). In that case, I really only need the id, since anyone who is interested in the new value ends up fetching it later anyway.

Sometimes I'm notifying "hey, there's a new entry in a join table", in which case I don't have an id field but instead have something like documents_id and profiles_id.

I *could* just write a bunch of different notify_create functions, for each scenario. I'd *prefer* to have one that did something like

```
row_to_json(NEW.filter(t => typeof t === 'number'))
```

to mix together plpgsql and javascript notation, but I'm sure you get the point: only include those fields of NEW that are number typed

Is this possible, or should I just write a bunch of different notifiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily eliminate json objects of type other than `number`, e.g.:

```
with my_table(int1, text1, int2, date1, float1) as (
values
    (1, 'text1', 100, '2017-01-01'::date, 123.54)
)

select jsonb_object_agg(key, value) filter (where jsonb_typeof(value) = 'number')
from my_table,
jsonb_each(to_jsonb(my_table))


              jsonb_object_agg              
--------------------------------------------
 {"int1": 1, "int2": 100, "float1": 123.54}
(1 row)
```

The function below leaves only integers:

```
create or replace function leave_integers(jdata jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(key, value) 
    filter (
        where jsonb_typeof(value) = 'number'
        and value::text not like '%.%')
    from jsonb_each(jdata)
$$;

with my_table(int1, text1, int2, date1, float1) as (
values
    (1, 'text1', 100, '2017-01-01'::date, 123.54)
)

select leave_integers(to_jsonb(my_table))
from my_table;

      leave_integers      
--------------------------
 {"int1": 1, "int2": 100}
(1 row)
```

### Alternative (better) solution

This function checks Postgres types directly and returns values strictly from integer columns.

```
create or replace function integer_columns_to_jsonb(anyelement)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(key, value) 
    from jsonb_each(to_jsonb($1))
    where key in (
        select attname
        from pg_type t
        join pg_attribute on typrelid = attrelid
        where t.oid = pg_typeof($1)
        and atttypid = 'int'::regtype)
$$;
```

The example shows that the function eliminates some corner cases handled incorrectly by `leave_integers()`:

```
create table my_table (int1 int, int2 int, float1 float, text1 text);
insert into my_table values (1, 2, 3, '4');

select integer_columns_to_jsonb(t), leave_integers(to_jsonb(t))
from my_table t;

 integer_columns_to_jsonb |           leave_integers            
--------------------------+-------------------------------------
 {"int1": 1, "int2": 2}   | {"int1": 1, "int2": 2, "float1": 3}
(1 row)
```